# Procore TinyMCE

Tags: pagination, tinymce

We are using Procore estimating system and there is tinyMCE as text editor . Pagination is missing as default feature . Is there any way that we can add pagination ?
Thank you for any informations
Pagination .
Tried to do that with page break but no luck